# VB.NET - Adding items to a listview along with tag property

Tags: vb.net

I can add items to a listview this way:

```
ListViewItem.Items.Add("Text")
```

But how can I set the Tag property of that same item as the same loop?
I tried going

```
ListViewItem.Items(0).Tag = "something"
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.Add` returns a `ListViewItem`, you can set new item's `Tag` property directly after the call:

```
ListViewItem.Items.Add("Text").Tag = "something"
```

If you want to set more than 1 property, store it in a local variable then you can do what you want:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem
lvi = ListViewItem.Items.Add("Text")
lvi.Tag = "something"
lvi.BackColor = ...
```

Comment: Fantastic! :) So quick and easy! :)

Comment: @manji: No, -1 because you don't read the question tag. C# supremacy is a bad idea.

Comment: Supremacy? You are imagining things... I didn't pay attention to the tags & from the question it looked to me like c# (because most of the time it's c# on stackoverflow)

Comment: manji: because most of the time it's c# on stackoverflow, C# supremacy exactly.